# Change typeface of verbatim environment

Tags: fonts, verbatim, typefaces

I am new here and the following code is what I am testing. Is it possible to change the typeface of the words from a `.txt` file? Thank you for any kind help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \vskip5em
    \begin{center}\LARGE#1\end{center}
    \vskip5em}%
}

\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test section}
\subsubsection{Test section}
\paragraph{Test section}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}This document is for testing.
\Large
\verbatiminput{verb.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is possible, but it's better if you give some more information.

Comment: @egreg Here is a more complicated code of mine:

Comment: This doesn't explain what you'd like the font to be.

Comment: @egreg Oh yes...sorry. The file "verb.txt" is just a simple txt file.

Comment: If it is just simple text and you'd like to embed it into the normal text flow, just call `\input` instead of `\verbatiminput`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you. What if the text is a long one? If I have to use \verbatiminput , how could I change the typeface?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [`verbatim` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/verbatim.pdf) (section **2.2 The interfaces**, p 4):

> Let us start with the simple things. Sometimes it may be necessary to use a special
>   typeface for your verbatim text, or perhaps the usual computer modern typewriter
>   shape in a reduced size.
>   You may select this by redefining the macro `\verbatim@font`. This macro is
>   executed at the beginning of every verbatim text to select the font shape. Do not
>   use it for other purposes; ...

There is no *interface* provided to change this, so you can include

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\verbatimfont}[1]{\def\verbatim@font{#1}}%
\makeatother
```

in your document preamble and then use `\verbatimfont{<font>}` to set the font as needed. Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}% http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\verbatimfont}[1]{\def\verbatim@font{#1}}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
This is some verbatim text in an external file.
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\verbatiminput{file.tex}

\verbatimfont{\itshape\ttfamily}
\verbatiminput{file.tex}

\verbatimfont{\scshape}
\verbatiminput{file.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133441/how-to-set-font-size-for-all-verbatims-in-beamer-presentation also has a good answer

Answer (score 4):

The `verbatimbox` package was created to put verbatim into boxes.  But the convenient optional argument was useful enough where I made "nobox" versions of the environments.  `verbnobox` is, in essence, an unboxed verbatim environment that takes optional arguments that can change the print style.

If you wanted to print a file in verbatim, the nobox version of that is `\verbfilenobox[optional arguments]{filename}`.  This just like a `\verbatiminput`, but with a convenient optional-argument-mechanism for changing fonts, fontsize, line numbering, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbnobox}[\sffamily]
 This \is a &^%$ verbatim in sffamily
\end{verbnobox}

\begin{verbnobox}[\itshape]
 This \is a &^%$ verbatim in itshape
\end{verbnobox}


\end{document}
```

[image]