# How to set font size for all verbatims in Beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, fontsize, verbatim

I'm trying to read through the Beamer manual, but I don't even really know what I'm looking for, so please help.

How do I change globally (but even if it is a per-frame, it will be still good) size of the verbatim blocks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to the preamble of your script:

```
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim{\tiny\@verbatim \frenchspacing\@vobeyspaces \@xverbatim}
\makeatother
```

This should globally change any verbatim environment in your document. Just change

```
\tiny
```

to whatever font size you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a follow-up question, somewhat related. I tried to add `:BEAMER_envargs: [size=small]` property to the particular frame (it contained only verbatim block). Wouldn't there be any way to define this on a per-frame level?

Comment: you should be able to define a new command. Something like `\newcommand\totiny{\tiny\selectfont}`. You can then add the `\totiny` command to any frame that you are creating. A frame in which the `\totiny` command is used will have tiny font. A frame in which the command is not used will use the default settings.

Answer (score 4):

The best strategy for this is to load the `fancyvrb` package; with

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\footnotesize}
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{}
```

your `verbatim` environments will *all* be printed using `\footnotesize`. If you want to override the setting for a particular environment, you can say

```
\begin{verbatim}[fontsize=\huge]
```

(well, maybe not `\huge`, that's only to give the idea); or issue

```
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}
```

inside a frame for the setting to hold only in that frame.

Of course you know that frames containing verbatim material should be announced by `\begin{frame}[fragile]`.

Comment: Can I ask you please to move it back to SO? This question was specific to `org-mode` of Emacs. It was by chance that it was possible to solve it through using some LaTeX code directly, but my original intention / expectation was that it would be possible to solve it by the means of `org-mode` (eg. through properties). Also, as a side effect of moving this question you made it impossible for the authors of other answers to reply to the comment, if there will be any.

Comment: @wvxvw What has the Beamer manual to do with Emacs' `org-mode`? What has `org-mode` to do with the typesetting of LaTeX material?

Comment: `org-mode` has settings to export to TeX, and then to export TeX to PDF. Beamer manual was a poor choice of words, I was referring to http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/beamer/ox-beamer.html (Worg manual) on Beamer export.

Comment: @wvxvw Changing the font size must be done on the LaTeX side nonetheless.

Comment: The page I'm referring to, for example, shows how to change font weight, maybe there's also an option to change the size? I don't know, but it seems fairly reasonable to believe there might be one. I mean, what if there is already a function for it in `org-mode`, but I simply don't know it's there? It may as well just do the same what has been suggested here.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could try to use the 'verbatim' package. I do this with:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{\scriptsize\ttfamily}
\makeatother
```

which changes the size of all verbatims to scriptsize.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Since I'm relatively new to LaTeX, would you mind telling how do you discover what packages are there and what features they provide?

Comment: This will change the font also in all inline `\verb` commands. Loading `verbatim` is not necessary, as `\verbatim@font` is a feature of the LaTeX kernel.