# Change font only for verbatim part of the document

Tags: fonts, verbatim

I need to set a certain monospace font only for the `verbatim` parts of the document. How can one do this?

For example, I understand that the commands

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be typewriter style
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

will set the font for the entire document, not solely for the `verbatim` part.

Comment: Do not redefine `\familydefault` but \ttfamily (i.e., `\renewcommand\ttfamily{\sffamily}` for instance)

Comment: Additional duplicate suggestions: [How to set font size for all `verbatim`s in `beamer` presentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133441/5764); [Change font size of the `verbatim` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171803/5764)

Answer (score 5):

Do not redefine `\familydefault` but `\ttfamily`,  i.e.:

```
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{txtt} % or ...
\renewcommand\ttfamily{\sffamily}
```

But you can do that simply loading a monospaced font:

```
\usepackage{nimbusmono} % for instance
```

Or using `xelatex` (or `lualatex`):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Bitstream Vera Sans}
```

[The LaTeX Font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html) explain the particular setting of every monospaced typewriter font.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, this is what `\verbatim@font` is for. Example setting this font to `newtxtt` family in `T1` encoding, medium series and upright shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\let\normalttdefault\ttdefault
\usepackage{newtxtt}
\let\ttdefault\normalttdefault  % restore normal \ttdefault

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\verbatim@font}{\usefont{T1}{newtxtt}{m}{n}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\texttt{This is typeset with cmtt. Look for instance at the *, \textdollar\ and
  @ characters. What follows is verbatim and uses a different font:}
\begin{verbatim}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
a += 2*(1 + l[44])
l = {1,...5}
#~&\^@_|3/%$÷`'"
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image: newtxtt verb]

For comparison, the default verbatim font (`cmtt` when using pdfTeX) gives:

[image: cmtt verb]

This was obtained with:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\texttt{This is typeset with cmtt. Look for instance at the *, \textdollar\ and
  @ characters. What follows is verbatim and uses the same font:}
\begin{verbatim}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
a += 2*(1 + l[44])
l = {1,...5}
#~&\^@_|3/%$÷`'"
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```