# How do I make default's monospace font smaller?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, fontsize, font-encodings, size

I thought the task would be so easy I will be able find an answer in a second. As it turned out, I can't make my `verb| |` look smaller without changing the "global" settings (which isn't what I want). I want to set a scale factor or a font size a bit smaller for the default's (I guess it's CM) typewriter font. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
% expect something like this \usepackage[scale=0.9]{monospacefont}
\begin{document}
Hello \verb|world|
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you just want to change the font size for `\verb(*)` and `verbatim(*)`, and keep the font size unchanged for `\ttfamily` and `\texttt`? If so, you can redefine `\verbatim@font`. For example, to append `\small`, use `\renewcommand*\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily\small}`.

Comment: Yes, you got me right. However, your solution doesn't work. It breaks the verbatim layout and prints `@` at the beginning. Also, it does not affect the `\verb`. I think something is misspelled. I think you are close to the right answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer.

```
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{\small\ttfamily}
\makeatother
```

It doesn't matter where you put it (before or after `\begin{document}`). It changes the font size only for `verb` and `verbatim` environment. `\small` is where you need to put the size that fits your needs.

Originally posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133443/137390).