# Decreasing font size in verbatim

Tags: fonts, verbatim

How can I modify the following command to make it work?

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\begingroup \fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont \begin{verbatim} #1 \end{verbatim} \endgroup}
```

I currently get the following error on the close of the following `verbatim` block:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...endgroup ^^M^^M$\eta_{xi} = r_{xi} -
                                                   q_i \cdot p_x$ \\^^M$q_i ...
l.227     \end{verbatim}
```

Comment: You may be interested in [Change typeface by using `verbatim` package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120633/5764), although passing code as arguments is not covered there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) is the de-facto standard for typesetting of code these days and offers syntax highlighting and font selection, amongst other things; [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) might be easier to handle for your use case.

To answer your more immediate question: you can't put the argument of a command into a `verbatim` environment, `verbatim` needs to change the way text is read and it's too late for that then.

Answer (score 19):

You can also place the `verbatim` environment inside a `small` environment:

```
\begin{small}
\begin{verbatim}
\LaTeX
\end{verbatim}
\end{small}
```

Source: https://www.namsu.de/latex/kapitel5.html

Comment: Not really. Without a blank line before `\begin{small}` you get wrong line spacing in the text above the `verbatim` material.

Comment: Also `small` is not an environment...

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that this answer works. You can also do `\begin{footnotesize}`.

Comment: I confirm that it works for \begin{footnotesize}

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `verbatim` environment; just patch it so that it selects a smaller font. In the example I use `\small` which is 9pt, 10pt or 11pt when the main font size is 10pt, 11pt or 12pt respectively.

Instead of `\small` you can substitute any other `\fontsize{X}{Y}\selectfont` instruction, but keep in mind that `Y` stands for the baseline skip, which should be larger than the font size `X`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@verbatim}
  {\verbatim@font}
  {\verbatim@font\small}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is text to show the font size
\begin{verbatim}
This is smaller
\end{verbatim}
Some other text
\end{document}
```

Explanation: `\verbatim@font` selects the typewriter type font; by adding `\small` we force it to another size.

[image]

Just to make clearer that it works, I repeat the output with `\tiny` instead of `\small`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `verbatimbox` package can take optional arguments, such as `\fontsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbnobox}[\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\selectfont]
Thi$ i$ my \/erbatim
text
\end{verbnobox}
\begin{verbnobox}[\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont]
Thi$ i$ my \/erbatim
text
\end{verbnobox}
\end{document}
```

[image]