# Formatting R arrays in LaTeX Beamer

Tags: beamer, r

I have an R array output that I would like to include in a LaTeX beamer slide.

The array is simple enough

```
, , 1

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

but seems a nightmare to format quickly and easily using the amsmath package and \begin{array}[cccccc] and \end{array}[cccccc].

Does someone know of a nice solution?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You could use a online table generator  https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Doesn't get much simpler than this!

Comment: Or print the table verbatim: `\begin{frame}[fragile]\begin{verbatim}[copy your array here]\end{verbatim}\end{frame}`, if needed you can make the text smaller using the solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161678/decreasing-font-size-in-verbatim.

Comment: @Marijn I completely forgot about \verbatim ! Easier than the table generator!

Comment: @Marijn Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter as requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `varbatim` environment for data such as program outputs. Note that the beamer frame needs to be `fragile` for this environment.

The font size can be changed by patching `\verbatim@font` with `etoolbox`, as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161713.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% optional font size setting for verbatim text, can be removed
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@verbatim}
  {\verbatim@font}
  {\verbatim@font\tiny}     % set font size here
  {}{}
\makeatother
% end of optional font size setting

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]{50 tiny fragile top-aligned NAs}
\begin{verbatim}
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that for displaying source code (e.g., R scripts) it is usually preferred to use packages like [`listings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) or [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted).