# Change font size of the verbatim environment

Tags: fontsize, verbatim

I want to apply small fonts inside the Verbatim environment e.g.

```
{\small 
\begin{Verbatim}

1   double x, y;
2   double z, w;
3   main();
4   return 0;

\end{Verbatim}}
```

Before the command `\small` and after the closing braket `}` text has normal size, which is obvious but the font size should be small inside the brakets.

> Why is this command not applied to the environment's contents?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. The environment `Verbatim` resets the font size to `\normalsize`.

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120633/change-typeface-of-verbatim-environment because changing size has different problems than changing typeface.

Answer (score 50):

You appear to be using `fancyvrb`, which already has the feature you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small]
1   double x, y;
2   double z, w;
3   main();
4   return 0;
\end{Verbatim}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For those using `\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}`, notice that here `Verbatim` is written with a capital `V`.

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned in [Change typeface of verbatim environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120633/5764), the default font used in `verbatim` is `\ttfamily`, as set in `\verbatim@font`. You can create a user interface to adjust this font in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\verbatimfont}[1]{\renewcommand{\verbatim@font}{\ttfamily#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\verbatimfont{\small}%
\begin{verbatim}
1   double x, y;
2   double z, w;
3   main();
4   return 0;
\end{verbatim}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

The macros of the `verbatimbox` package can take things like `\small` as an optional argument.  In this case, I chose the `verbnobox` environment, but there are others in that package than may better suit your need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\noindent Normal Size
\begin{verbnobox}[\small]

1   double x, y;
2   double z, w;
3   main();
4   return 0;

\end{verbnobox}
Normal Size
\end{document}
```

[image]

Furthermore, you could ask the package to number the lines for you, instead of you doing it manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\noindent Normal Size
\begin{verbnobox}[\tiny\arabic{VerbboxLineNo}\small\hspace{3ex}]
double x, y;
double z, w;
main();
return 0;
\end{verbnobox}
Normal Size
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend the package `listings`, which is ment for this purpose. See the page on [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings) for simple explanations about settings and my MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{ %
language=C++,           % choose the language of the code
numbers=left,           % where to put the line-numbers
numberstyle=\tiny,      % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
basicstyle=\footnotesize    % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum
{\footnotesize Lorem ipsum
\begin{lstlisting}
double x, y;
double z, w;
main();
return 0;
\end{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

I replaced `\small` by `\footnotesize` in order to emphasize the different sizes:

[image: Output contents]