# How to use \scalebox around my environment?

Tags: fontsize, text-manipulation, technical-environment

I tried putting scalebox{.2} while defining my new environment, but it is not being applied:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{myenvironment}[0]
{scalebox{.2}\{myenvironment start\par\verbatim}
{\endverbatim\endgraf myenvironment end\}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{myenvironment}
    test
\end{myenvironment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to use \scalebox around my environment?

Comment: Related to [Change font size of the verbatim environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171803/change-font-size-of-the-verbatim-environment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to do this with the `verbatimbox` package.  Note that approach two requires a scalable font, which is why I added the `lmodern` package.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx,verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbbox}
test
of my
\%\@# verbatim stuff
\end{verbbox}
\noindent\scalebox{.2}{\theverbbox} 

versus normal size

\begin{verbnobox}[\fontsize{2pt}{2.5pt}\selectfont]
test
of my
\%\@# verbatim stuff
\end{verbnobox}

Back to normal
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but when I use the font size directive I got these warnings depending on the font size: ``LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/n' in size <2> not available(Font)              size <5> substituted on input line 94.`` However while using the `scalebox` it does not show these things.

Comment: @user Note that I added `\usepackage{lmodern}` to the preamble.

Comment: Thanks! I added it to my preamble and fixed the warnings.

Comment: Is there any way to keep blank lines in  \verbbox  or \verbnobox ?

Comment: @user1389406 Yes.  Add `\mbox{}` to `\begin{verbnobox}[\fontsize{2pt}{2.5pt}\selectfont\mbox{}]` in the invocation, so that even blank lines get prepended with an empty mbox.

Comment: Thank you Steven. It works like a charm.

Comment: @user1389406 The `\mbox` takes one out of vertical mode.  Therefore, one could, likewise, substitute `\leavevmode` in lieu of `\mbox{}`.

Answer (score 4):

Or use the `environ` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{test}{%
\scalebox{5}{\BODY}}

\begin{document}
    This is nuts
\begin{test}
    This is nuts
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While the OP's question did not use the words, his/her MWE indicated verbatim content.

Comment: Ah, hadn't noticed that...

Comment: Well, this works with not font size warnings, but I could not put the verbatim on it. I tried: ``\NewEnviron{myenvironment}{\scalebox{.2}{\par\verbatim \BODY \endverbatim\endgraf}}``

Comment: Ha, just came across this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51239/verbatim-in-environ-s-body Seems to answer yours.

Answer (score 1):

Quite similar to [\scalebox in column specification operator >{...}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/648993/250119), however `verbatim` also cannot be put inside `hbox` so you need the primitive `setbox` as suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41707/250119:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newbox\mybox
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newenvironment{myenvironment}[0]
{
    \setbox\mybox\vbox\bgroup
    myenvironment~start
    \par
    \verbatim}
{
    \endverbatim
    \endgraf myenvironment~end
    \egroup
    \scalebox{.2}{\box\mybox}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{myenvironment}
    test
\end{myenvironment}
\end{document}
```

I prefer `\ExplSyntaxOn`, but you can also `%` every lines.

Comment: Using minipage doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want verbatim mode, you can use `fancyvrb`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{myenvironment}
 {\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}\begin{BVerbatim}}
 {%
  \end{BVerbatim}\end{lrbox}%
  \par\smallskip\hrule\smallskip % or whatever you want at the top
  \noindent\scalebox{.2}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
  \par\smallskip\hrule\smallskip % or whatever you want at the bottom
  \@endpetrue
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text before the scaled verbatim
some text before the scaled verbatim
some text before the scaled verbatim
\begin{myenvironment}
test
\end{myenvironment}
Some text after the scaled verbatim
some text after the scaled verbatim
some text after the scaled verbatim

\end{document}
```

[image]