# How are these texttt fonts different?

Tags: fonts, listings, verbatim

Below are two examples of fonts.  The first is from the `verbatim` environment (which [I read has default font `ttfamily`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171866)).  The second is from a `lstlisting` with `basicstyle=\ttfamily`.  They look different.  It looks like the second has more space between the letters.  What is happening?  And how to I get the `lstlisting` example to look like the `verbatim` example?

[image: two code fonts]

Comment: Look for `basewidth` in the `listings` documentation to adjust the width for every character. If you want a more detailed answer, you should add a MWE.

Comment: Please consider to **upvote and/or accept the provided answer** so that the process comes to an end :).

Answer (score 5):

Like hinted by [@MarcelKrüger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599275/how-are-these-texttt-fonts-different#comment1502312_599275) the difference has to do with the `basewidth` key of `listings`.

`listings` prints its output to a fixed width (that can be specified with `\lstset{basewidth=<width>}`, or in the optional argument of `lstlisting`), this way also proportional fonts can be used for code listings.

You can turn this column format off by using `columns=fullflexible`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
some code about stuff
other code about stuff
\end{verbatim}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible]
some code about stuff
other code about stuff
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

Comment: @dfrankow usually we don't say thank you via comments but via votes. But I'm glad I could help.