# Change Verbatim Font To PCR

Tags: fonts, formatting, verbatim

I'm writing a document using LaTeX, and I would like to use the PCR font inside of a verbatim block.  [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120633/change-typeface-of-verbatim-environment) is almost identical to mine, but when I try to apply it to use PCR, I can't get it to work.

**This is what I am trying:**

```
% From the question I linked above:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\verbatimfont}[1]{\def\verbatim@font{#1}}%
\makeatother

...

\verbatimfont{pcr}
\begin{verbatim}
This should be in pcr.
\end{verbatim}
```

It simply outputs:

> pcrThis should be in pcr.

It works fine with `\verbatimfont{\scshape}`, but I can't get it to work with an actual custom font.  Do I need to make my own `\pcr` command to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pcr` is the family name, it is used with `\fontfamily`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\verbatimfont}[1]{\def\verbatim@font{#1}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\verbatimfont{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}
\begin{verbatim}
This should be in pcr.
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Or

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\verbatimfontfamily}[1]{%
  \def\verbatim@font{\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\verbatimfontfamily{pcr}
\begin{verbatim}
This should be in pcr.
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Or with a `\pcr` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\verbatimfont}[1]{%
  \def\verbatim@font{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\pcr}{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\verbatimfont{\pcr}
\begin{verbatim}
This should be in pcr.
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Ah! Thanks. That worked magnificently. It says I can accept the answer in 10 minutes. :D
I like that modification to the original command, too.

Answer (score 2):

Verbatim environments and macros in the `verbatimbox` package accept optional arguments that can change the font, font size, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}  
\begin{verbnobox}[\scriptsize]
Testing scriptsize cmtt verbatim
\end{verbnobox}
\begin{verbnobox}[\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont]
Testing pcr verbatim
\end{verbnobox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to look into that package.  I've seen it around, but I haven't tried it.