# Resize verbatim in exponent equation mode

Tags: equations, verbatim

I have this inline equation

```
$2^{\verb|N|-1}$
```

that gives this result

[image]

The problem is that using `\verb|N|` leaves `N` with the same size as in `\displaystyle` but I want it to be smaller.

How can I do?

Comment: why are you using `\verb` here? That seems fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe, it is a code variable of a computer program. Such code variable names could have underscores, colons, ... But, I agree, type writer font is not the best choice for mathematical variables. Then just `$2^{N-1}$` will do better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternatives with automatically resized `N`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}% or package amsmath for \text
\newcommand*{\ttmath}[1]{%
  \texttt{\mdseries\upshape#1}%
}

\begin{document}

  $2^{\verb|N|-1}$ {\small(\verb|\verb|)}

  $2^{\texttt{N}-1}$ {\small(\verb|\texttt| with \verb|amstext|)}

  \textit{Italics $2^{\ttmath{N}-1}$ context} {\small(macro \verb|\ttmath|)}

  $2^{\mathtt{N}-1}$ {\small(\verb|\mathtt|)}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\texttt` here works with automatically resizing in math mode because it internally uses `\nfss@text` that is redefined in package `amstext` as `\text`.
- Macro `\ttmath` also resets font attributes series and shape to get independent from the current text font setting.
- `\mathtt` is the most efficient command and uses the configured typewriter font for math. This is often the same as `\ttfamily`. Some font packages switch both fonts at the same time as `lmodern`, others do not as `beramono`. Therefore, it depends on the font setup, whether `\mathtt` can be used instead of `\verb` or `\texttt`.

Comment: If used in a theorem statement (or other italic context), the second solution can lead to surprising results. By the way, `\text` is not necessary. In my opinion just `\mathtt{N}` should be suggested.

Comment: @egreg If the surrounding text is italics, then `\upshape` can be used (`\text{\ttfamily\upshape N}`). `\mathtt` and `\ttfamily` can be different fonts. Then, `\mathtt` cannot be used as substitute for `\texttt`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

The LaTeX kernel defines `\mathtt` and nothing else is necessary. By the way, `\verb` should not be abused for printing in the typewriter font, usually `\texttt` is enough, whereas `\verb` is needed for printing TeX code with special characters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$2^{\mathtt{N}-1}$

$2^{\mathtt{N}^{\mathtt{M}}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's probably useful to define your own semantic command, say

```
\newcommand{\tvar}[1]{\mathtt{#1}}
```

and use `$2^{\tvar{N}}$`. This way you're not tied to the particular representation that you can change at any time by just modifying the definition.

It may happen that the choice of a different font set doesn't update `\mathtt`. The solution is simple and the advantage over other solutions involving `\text` is that this can be easily adapted to support `\boldmath` out of the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % necessary for beramono
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{beramono}

% update \mathtt to use the same font as \ttfamily
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{m}{n}
% if the monospaced font also supports boldface (b or bx)
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathtt}{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{b}{n}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

$2^{\mathtt{N}-1}$ and \texttt{N}

\begin{theorem}
Something about $2^{\mathtt{N}-1}$
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Side note

Using `\texttt` is wrong, as exemplified by the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tvar}[1]{\mathtt{#1}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section*{Right}

$2^{\tvar{N}-1}$

\begin{theorem}
Something about $2^{\tvar{N}-1}$
\end{theorem}

\section*{Wrong}

$2^{\texttt{N}-1}$

\begin{theorem}
Something about $2^{\texttt{N}-1}$
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try other font packages like `beramono` or `libertine`. Then the glyph forms of `N` differ for `\verb|N|`/`\texttt{N}` and `\mathtt{N}`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek That's quite easy to solve anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using this answer of Werner: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120694/120578

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}% http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatimes
\usepackage{pgf}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mverbatimfont}{\def\verbatim@font{\ttfamily}}%
\makeatother
\def\verbatimfont#1{\pgfmathsetmacro\bls{1.2*#1}\mverbatimfont\fontsize{#1}{\bls}\selectfont}


\begin{document}
\verbatimfont{6}
$2^{\verb|N|-1}$

\verbatimfont{9}
$\verb|N|^{\verbatimfont{6}\verb|N|-1}$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Doubtful that the OP wants to have a smaller verbatim font size for all verbatim text including outside of sub- and superscripts. Consider the following formula: `$\verb|N|^{\verb|N|-1}$`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I thought that the OP really needed a verbatim environment and added o solution for that.... Anyway fixed it for such cases too with verbatim environment and manually changing the fontsize. I could automate it too, but seems that doesn't really want to use verbatim but just it's fontfamilly... If someone else need something like what I did automated he may ask for it