# How to change the font size of verbatiminput to footnotesize?

Tags: fontsize, verbatim

I'm using the following code in latex for inserting R output from the package verbatim. First I put the output in a text file then call it from the following code,

```
\verbatiminput{2.txt}
```

The font size is a bit big. How can I change the font size to footnotesize for all the command \verbatiminput{}?

Comment: Redefine `\verbatim@font` to add size-switching commands. `\verbatim@font` is initially defined as `\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily \hyphenchar\font\m@ne \@noligs}`. This info can be found by searching for "font" in the [doc of package `verbatim`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/verbatim.pdf).

Comment: Can you help me how this is done? I'm new to latex.

Comment: Related: [Change typeface of verbatim environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120694/79060)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```tex
\begin{filecontents}[noheader]{2.txt}
This is file "2.txt".
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto\verbatim@font{\footnotesize}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Normal text\par
{\footnotesize Footnote-size text}
\verbatiminput{2.txt}
\end{document}
```

[image]