# How do I change the default font size of verbatim at document level?

Tags: verbatim

I know how I can change the font size of a verbatim text. For example:

```
\begin{tiny}
\begin{verbatim}
My verbatim text is tiny in size
\end{verbatim}
\end{tiny}
```

Is there a way to specify that all my verbatim text in the current document should have a tiny font-size so that I avoid enclosing each of my verbatim text in `\tiny`?

Thanks!

Comment: @User23456234 I'm a tex newbie, can you show me how to do that exactly?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120633/change-typeface-of-verbatim-environment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing `\verbatim@font` might be the solution, but it would also change the font for inline `\verb`.

Better adding `\scriptsize` (or `\tiny` if you want your readers to hate you) when `verbatim` starts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginEnvironment{verbatim}{\scriptsize}% or whatever

\begin{document}

This is text to show the \verb|font size|
\begin{verbatim}
This is smaller
\end{verbatim}
Some other text

\end{document}
```

[image]

With an older LaTeX release you might need `\usepackage{etoolbox}`.

Answer (score 5):

Adding the below will change the font size of verbatim in the entire document to, for example, `\tiny`.

```
\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@font{\tiny\ttfamily}
\makeatother
```