# How do I change the typeface in the \verbatim environment?

Tags: verbatim, typefaces

I am aware that this question has been asked before but it has not been answered to my satisfaction. It has been posted as an answer here ([Change typeface of verbatim environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120633/change-typeface-of-verbatim-environment)) that the only way to change the typeface in the verbatim environment is through the command

```
\newcommand{\verbatimfont}[1]{\def\verbatim@font{#1}}%
```

But that doesn't work if I want to use Inconsolata or IBM Sans. How do you do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document) In particular, verbatim environments rely on monospaced font, so if you want to use Inconsolata, you may want to consult the section on `fontspec` and `\setmonofont`.

Comment: Welcome. // Please provide a few lines of code which: a) start with \documentclass, b) ends with \end{document}, c) uses your \renewcommand, d) shows your problem i.e. doesn‘t change the verbatim font, so we can copy, compile, inspect. Thank you

Comment: Does both the mentioned fonts are free or commercial? Also, let us confirm what type of `TeX` engine you are using, i.e., `PDFLaTeX`, or `XeLaTeX`, etc.

Comment: verbatim normally used `\ttfamily` do yo want to change all monospace eg `\texttt{ABC}` or just verbatim?